# woocommerce add extra div after price in content-product.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

guys:
I want to add a extra div after price hook. Below is my code, but it is not working. Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong?

```
function init_actions() {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'see_details_button', 10 );
}

function see_details_button() {
    $button = '<div>See Details</div>';
    return $button;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only returning the string you want to output. Because this is an action and not a filter I think that you should print/echo the HTML instead, i.e:

```
echo '<div>See Details</div>';
```

If that does not work. Make sure that the action actually run at the right place and that the action name is correct.